# Show records based on the option selected in the select menu

Tags: sql, database

I have a products table, the products table has a column `available` of data type `boolean` if it's true the product is available if is false is not available.

So I have a select menu, but I'm in doubt about how to show the options "All" "Not Available" and "Available", these values can be static like below or should come from the DB?

```
 <select>
  <option value="0">Not Available</option>
  <option value="1">Available</option>
  <option value="2">All</option>
</select>
```

And then do you know how to do the sql query to get only records that have the availability column equal to the availability selected by the user and to show all if the user selects "All"? To get the products based on the availability selected by the user this should work:

```
Select * from products where availability = selectedOption
```

But then do you know how the query should be to show all products if the user selects "All" and also to show all the products by default when the page is accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets' tackle this questions one-by-one:

> So I have a select menu, but I'm in doubt about how to show the options "All" "Not Available" and "Available", these values can be static like below or should come from the DB?

This is up to you, you could have this options stored in your database and load it dynamically, or you could do the way you did (static options).

> And then do you know how to do the sql query to get only records that have the availability column equal to the availability selected by the user and to show all if the user selects "All"?

You didn't specify the language you are working on, but you are on the right track. You have to build this `select` statement dynamically, with the option selected by the user at the end as a `parameter`. However, for the "All" option work, you will have to do something like this (this is pseudo code, please adapt to your language):

```
if selectedOption === 'All' then
    select * from products
else
    select * from products where availability = selectedOption
```

Of course, there are variations to this code, this is just for you to get the idea.